# Is it possible to use forloop to get a same result as using expo function **

Tags: python

Everyone, I am a beginner in Python.

I want to know if I want to calculate a exponential function. Instead of using 
(base)**(power)

Can I create a forloop that will get me the same result?

Comment: Yes you can why don't you try it? You do know `base ** power` is simply `base` multipled power times right?

Comment: short answer, yes, this is possible

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea. I just don't know how to define the function so that base can be multiplied power times.

Comment: It's my first time to try to use two variables in a function. So please forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here's the basic:

```
def exponential(base,power):
    answer = 1
    for i in range(power):
        answer *= base
    return answer
```

Here's to include negative exponents:

```
def exponential(base,power):
    answer = 1
    if power < 0:
        for i in range(power * -1):
            answer /= base
    else:
        for i in range(power):
            answer *= base
    return answer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. More than what I want

Comment: @BowenLiu No problem! Feel free to hit the checkmark :)